# Constructor isn't printing as expected

Tags: java

```
public class Fraction
{
    public Franction(int n, int d)
    {
        int num = n;
        int denom = d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(5,10);
        System.out.println("Fraction = " + f1);
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm trying to learn Java... The book I'm working out of suggests that the output of the code above should print "Fraction = 5/10", but when I try it I just receive "Fraction = Fraction@33469a69" which I assume is printing the reference to where it is stored? I understand how it is suppose to work with the constructor I just don't receive the expected output. Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the desired output, you need to overload `toString()` method in the `Franction` class. This method is used to determine textual representation of the object. By default, it is `ClassName@hashCode`.

Also, you probably would like to store the values you receive in the constructor as fields. Right now, you store the numerator and denominator in constructor's local variables, that are destroyed as soon as the constructor exits.

Try something like this:

```
public class Fraction
{
    private final int num
    private final int denom;

    public Franction(int n, int d)
    {
        this.num = n;
        this.denom = d;
    }

    @Override
    String toString() 
    {
        return String.format("%d/%d", num, denom);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(5,10);
        System.out.println("Fraction = " + f1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `override` the `toString`() function in your `Fraction` class.

[As per docs of toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

So

```
  Fraction@33469a69  is the textual representation of Fraction class.
```

To get the  required output, write the logic in overridden `toString` method in Object class and  return the string there.

A simple `toString` implementation  looks like

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.append(this.someMemeber); //will be in String format
    result.append(this.someMemeber);
    return result.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `toString` method for the same

```
public String toString(){
  StringBuilder stringToReturn = new StringBuilder();
  stringToReturn.append(this.num);
  stringToReturn.append("/");
  stringToReturn.append(this.denom);

  return stringToReturn.toString();
}
```

Comment: 1: No need to specify an empty string when instantiating a StringBuilder. 2: You're concatenating within the append() method, which is exactly what StringBuilder tries to avoid (concatenation). 3: There's no i nor j in the OP.

Comment: @sp00m, correctet that. Is there anything I am missing again? I would like to know. and the empty string in StringBuilder constructor was a type :(

Comment: @sp00m, actually I read somewhere that strings shouldn't be used in toString method to operations thats why used a `StringBuilder` here. am I missing something?

Comment: I wasn't talking about your stringToReturn StringBuilder (which is the right way to do), but the nested one you used: `.append(new StringBuilder("/"))`. It looks already better now ;) You could have chained the append() methods (`.append(this.num).append("/").append(this.denom)`, but it's only a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class Fraction
{
    private int num;
    private int denom;
    public Franction(int n, int d)
    {
        num = n;
         denom = d;
    }

    public int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }

    public int getDenom()
    {
        return denom;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(5,10);
        System.out.println("Fraction = " + f1.getNum() + "/" + f1.getDenom());
    }
}
```

Alternative (Better way to do this)

```
public class Fraction
{
    private int num;
    private int denom;
    public Franction(int n, int d)
    {
        num = n;
         denom = d;
    }

    public int getNum()
    {
        return num;
    }

    public int getDenom()
    {
        return denom;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return (f1.getNum() + "/" + f1.getDenom());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(5,10);
        System.out.println("Fraction = " + f1 );
    }
}
```

You need to study more about encapsulation , the Object class and the toString() method.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public class Fraction {

    private final int num;
    private final int denom;

    public Fraction(int num, int denom) {
        this.num = num;
        this.denom = denom;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return num + "/" + denom;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(5, 10);
        System.out.println("Fraction = " + f1);
    }
}
```

You have to store the values in the object you create. Then override the `toString` method of `Object` to get your desired output.

Output:

```
Fraction = 5/10
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is printing out the Object.

If you want to print the contents of the Object you will to create a toString method in you class.

see http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55